# Static Hashtable in WebService

Tags: web-services, hashtable, c#-2.0

I have developed a simple XML web service which  uses a static hashtable for storing two column table from the database.
The hashtable is loaded with values initially in the first call to web service.
The web service works fine in the visual studio IDE.

When it is deployed in IIS (version 7.0), it throws a nullpointer exception.
The error message points to the function which is getting the pair values from the hashtable.

My question is:
1) Is it possible to store a static hashtable in the web service throughout the lifecycle of the web service.
2) Should the hashtable be checked everytime if it is null or not before accessing the hashtable?
3) what is the best way to use a static hashtable?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is that in production your web service is handling multiple simultaneous calls.  These calls appear as separate threads and they are accessing the single `HashTable` in an unsafe way.  These unsafe accesses are causing the internal data of the `HashTable` to be corrupted resulting in a `NullReferenceException`

You need to protect access to this `HashTable` with a lock to safely access it from a static field in a web service

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you pls guide me how to lock the hashtable.